# Admob Module 'GoogleMobileAds' not found

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm working on a video game written in C# using Unity 3d. So far it has been going well, but I have run into a major issue. I just implemented ads using Google's AdMob, and everything works great on android, but I am having serious problems getting it to run on IOS.

Currently I have an error on my `@import GoogleMobileAds` saying that the module is not found. I have been working on this problem for about 2 hours and none of the other solutions on Stack Overflow have helped.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and I managed to fix in this way:

1. I moved the iOS Admob SDK into the Xcode project folder (before it was in a different location, outside of the xcode project)
2. I selected yes for "Enable modules" and no for "Enable Bitcode" in Build Settings
3. Then I imported the GoogleMobileAds.framework

Comment: Where do I find this 'GoogleMobileAds.framework' file?

Comment: "I selected yes for "Enable modules" " work for me, thanks.